# WPF Binding relational ComboBox's from L2S with filtering on all of them

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, filtering

in a WPF project with Linq to SQL, if you use the O/R - designer to create a simple structure with 3 that are all tied with forgin key relataions like so:

Customer <-- Orders <-- Items,  and say i want a simpe window with 3 syncronized comboboxes
when you select a customer you see only his orders and when you select an Order you see only the Items for that Order. all of this is simple....

Lets say i want to add filtering capablities to all the comboboxes. how would i do that if i want to use the entity objects from the LINQ dbml file?

Edit - Elaborating on filtering.
i would like to filter the in memory collection without the need to query the database again, the filter can be a textbox that is over the combobox, that doest matter, my problem is that i cant filter the comboboxes because the are bound to an EntitySet through the L2S and dont implement filtering.

Thanks,
  Eric

Comment: can you elaborate on filtering capabilities you're interested in ?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using CollectionViewSource. Bea Stollnitz has a good primer on it [here](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=17) and I used [this blog post](http://sandyvalley.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AB1484B25F28E501!461.entry) to show me how to filter. This will let you filter and sort without having to use the database and is pretty fast.

Comment: This isnt what im looking for EntitySet implemetetion of IBindingLisView cannot filter. thats exactly the problem.